# How to Auto sort on one field in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, sorting

I am new to the MongoDB database.
Because the number of records is very large, it takes us a lot of time to sort them in each query.
I want to have a field called Id, like in SQL server, that I can set myself.
And when I retrieve the information from this table, the information will be returned to me sorted according to the Id field.
With my research, I found out that fields cannot be auto-incremented in NoSQL databases.
Now if we index on the Id field according to the following command:

```
db.users.createIndex({ Id: 1 })
```

When reading the information in this table, the records will be sorted by Id or do we need to re-sort in the query?

Comment: You have the _id field there (only field what all records must have) and it's first 4 bytes are timestamp. So, if you query db.collection.find().sort("_id":1) you get documents in time order.